# How to retrieve the values from the array of List<>

Tags: java, list

There are three arrays of list, list[0],list[1],list[2]
I want to fetch the list[1] which is giving the name of subjects and subjects are coming from the server.

Below is the output which I require:

**Student Subjects:**

Maths

Physics

Chemistry

Hindi

English

Moral Science

*But I am getting*

**Student Subjects:**

Maths

Physics

Chemistry

I am not getting why it is happening.

I am using this piece of code:

```
            List<Items>[] students = ActivityStudents.getStudentDetails();

            for (int i = 0; i < students[1].size(); i++) {
                subjects.append("\n" + students[1].get(i) + "\n");
            }
```

Please help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish nor what the issue/question is - could you please clarify? - also read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve the question, including formatting your code correctly for others to find it easy to help

Comment: This isn't a `List` filled with an array, this is an array of `List<Item>`s.

Comment: Could you include your `getStudentDetails()` declaration of the function at least.

Comment: @Zircon, sorry for the typo mistake, you are correct

Comment: please check the edits

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on the lists of items to be of equal length. This is obviously not the case. As you describe it `lists[0]` contains 3 elements, `lists[1]` contains 6. You only collect as many items as you find in `lists[0]`, so you stop at 3.

While I do not understand the datastructure, which is possibly not required, you should count to the maximum list-size and then handle shorter lists in the loop.

Or loop over the lists seperately.

```
List<Items> results = new ArrayList<Items>();
List<Items>[] lists = ActivityStudents.getStudentDetails();

int maxIdx = Math.max(lists[0].size(), lists[1].size();
maxIdx = Math.max(maxIdx, lists[2].size());

for (int i = 0; i < maxIdx; i++) {
    Items items= new Items(SOURCE);
    if( i < lists[0].size() ) items.set("STUDENT", lists[0].get(i));
    if( i < lists[1].size() ) items.set("SUBJECTS", lists[1].get(i));
    if( i < lists[2].size() ) items.set("MARKS", lists[2].get(i));
    results.add(items);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..will try it. Also list[0],list[1],lis[2] all contains 6 elements. In the first part of my coding, no changes needed, change is to be done in another class

Comment: It doesn't give me exact solution. I am getting 6,6,6. I dont want the number. I want to show  list[1] items names.